# Release DLL after creation in BuildManager

Tags: c#, .net, dll, build, msbuild

I have written an C# WPF Application to compile code during runtime. The application does basically the following steps

1. click button [Compile stuff]
2. Create code files via `StreamWriter`
3. Build code files using the `Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager` class
4. Uses reflection to access the DLL file (`Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath)`)
5. creates an instanz of the class contained in the dll (`assembly.CreateInstance(NamespaceName + "." + ClassName)`)

**I works fine, but only once** (I need to restart the application to do it again)

This is what happens during the next execution

1. click button [Compile stuff]
2. Create code files via `StreamWriter`
3. Build code files using the `Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager` class
   ->Produces an error saying that the DLL file is locked.

> The process cannot access the file 'DLL\generatedflexform.dll' because
>   it is being used by another process

The problem doesn't occur when I leave out step 2 because then the code files are the same. Therefore the `BuildManager` doesn't recreate/copy the dll.

I need to figure out how to release the DLL after the `BuildManager` has done his job. This is because the code files are likely to change very often and otherwise i have to close and re-open the application for every code change.

EDIT: My first thought was that the BuildManager causes the locking but this is not the case.
I rather think the locking happens when I try to load the DLL. I will try the Shadow Copy think (as mentioned by @granadaCoder).

```
private Window LoadWindowFromDll(string filePathToDll)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePathToDll);
    var window = assembly.CreateInstance(NamespaceName + "." + ClassName) as Window;
    return window;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I had to change the `LoadWindowFromDllmethod` to avoid the DLL locking

```
private Window LoadWindowFromDll(string filePathToDll)
{
    byte[] readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePathToDll);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(readAllBytes);

    var window = assembly.CreateInstance(NamespaceName + "." + ClassName) as Window;

    return window;
}
```

But somehow the pdb file was locked which causes the build to failed when I try to execute it twice.

I fixed this behavior by adding one line to my build file:

```
<DebugType>none</DebugType>
```

Here is the complete build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>generatedflexform</AssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>DLL\</OutputPath>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="MyForm.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="MyForm.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MyForm.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

And here comes the method which does the compile magic>
        public Window BuildXamlWindowFromStrings(string xaml, string codeBehind)
        {
            //Erstellen der Codefiles (XAML und CodeBehind)
            this.CreateCodeFile(codeBehind);
            this.CreateXamlFile(xaml);

```
        //Erstellen der project file
        this.CreateProjectFile();

        //Build der DLL
        //using (var buildManager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager)
        using (var buildManager = new BuildManager())
        {
            var result = buildManager.Build(this.CreateBuildParameters(), this.CreateBuildRequest());

            if (result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
            {
                return this.LoadWindowFromDll(FolderPath + DllRelativeFilePath + NamespaceName + DllFileExtension);
            }
        }

        //Error handling
        var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(DebuggerLogFileName))
        {
            stringbuilder.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        throw new CompilerException(stringbuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Helper Methods:

```
private BuildParameters CreateBuildParameters()
{
    var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
    var buildLogger = new FileLogger { Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed, Parameters = "logfile=" + DebuggerLogFileName };
    var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(projectCollection) { Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { buildLogger } };
    return buildParameters;
}

private BuildRequestData CreateBuildRequest()
{
    var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(FolderPath + ProjectFileName, globalProperties, null,
                                            new string[] { "Build" }, null, BuildRequestDataFlags.ReplaceExistingProjectInstance);
    return buildRequest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution so other can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Shadow Copying".

Shadow copying enables assemblies that are used in an application domain to be updated without unloading the application domain. This is particularly useful for applications that must be available continuously.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx

See also:

http://gotchahunter.net/2010/12/net-how-do-you-load-an-assembly-programmatically-and-avoid-a-file-lock/

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/09/69919.aspx

Comment: Shadow Copying seems to be really nice but also a bit overkill for my purpose. however I found another solution.